# Closing boost::asio::serial_port with pending read_async_some

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, serial-port, boost-asio

I am chaining `read_async_some()` calls to asynchronously read from a serial port. At some point, I need to cancel the asynchronous reads using and detect this fact in the associated handlers. From [the documentation for `cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/cancel/overload1.html), I expected to do so simply by checking the `error_code` passed to my handlers:

> This function causes all outstanding asynchronous read or write
>   operations to finish immediately, and the handlers for cancelled
>   operations will be passed the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error.

However, when I try this, my handlers are called with the `invalid_argument` error instead of the expected `operation_aborted` error. Here is a minimal example that reproduces the issue by using a ptty to emulate a serial port:

```
void handle(boost::system::error_code const& error, size_t count)
{
    std::cout << "error_code = " << error.message() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::fstream fs("/dev/ttyp0", std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port serial(io, "/dev/ttyp0");

    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(1);
    serial.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
        boost::bind(&handle,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        )
    );

    boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
    serial.cancel();
    thread.join();
    fs.close();
}
```

At least for me, the output of this program is `error_code = Invalid argument`. Can anyone explain why I am not getting the behavior described in the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind. In case anyone else runs into the same problem, the issue was actually with using pttys for testing. As it turns out, pttys don't behave properly when used for asynchronous input and `boost::asio` indicates this problem with the above error message.

I was able to solve this issue by creating a simulated loopback serial port with `socat`. There are good instructions for doing so in [this blog post](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/howto-vsp-socat/).